# The difference between 丸 and 玉

Tags: kanji-choice

It may be a dumb question, both mean circle/round thing but 玉 is more of a jewel/sphere/ball. Could I say "5円丸" instead of "5円玉"? Or should I just stick with "5円硬貨"

Answer (score 3):

When I was a kid, some older people did actually called coins as:

> 「[Number] 円丸{えんまる}」

Now that those people are gone, I no longer encounter that usage anywhere.  It might have been a regional (Nagoya, in my case) and/or old way of calling coins.  You would look quite weird if you used it today.

In informal daily speech, we almost exclusively use:

> 「[number] 円玉{えんだま}」

Only in very formal situations, we use:

> 「[Number] 円硬貨{えんこうか}」

Most people just do not actively use the last one much even though everyone knows what it means.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard people say "x円丸".

It's weird that we never refer coins as "玉", but we always say like "十円玉".
You could say like "一円硬貨", but it's like "coinage"; too rigid word to use.

To mention coins, we use "小銭{こぜに}", or more specifically "x円玉{えんだま}".